# Keypress event if NOT input

Tags: jquery, events, exception, if-statement, key

I have the following jQuery events in my site

```
    $(window).keyup (function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 68:  // Alt-N = next
                scroll ('next');
                break;
            case 65:  // Alt-P = prev
                scroll ('prev');
                break;

        }

});

});

 <script>
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==68){
        window.location.href = "{PreviousPost}";
    }
    });
</script>
```

I'm using window and document because they both work and searching didn't result in me finding out what the difference is in terms of functionality. But anyway, what I'm wondering is how to keep the functions from firing, when it's in an input field. Cause it works and everything, but I don't want the event to fire when the user is typing only when they press the keys and are ... not typing.

It seems simple, but I really searched. Kept giving me results from other issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the event:

```
if ($(e.target).closest("input")[0]) {
    return;
}
```

What that does is see if the target originates in or passes through an `input` element and return without doing anything if so. More: [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) | [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) Your logic for other cases would follow, e.g.:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("input")[0]) {
        return;
    }
    if(e.keyCode==68){
        window.location.href = "{PreviousPost}";
    }
});
```

N.B. - If you also want to filter out `select` elements, then: `$(e.target).closest("input, select")` (and so on, for instance for `button` elements).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have limited knowledge with jQuery but that does look like what I need. However adding that makes everything stop working. I can put up a jsfiddle if you want.

Comment: Why are you using closest() here, i don't understand it?

Comment: @roasted: Fair point, `input` can't contain other elements. `select` can (`option`s), but I don't know if keypresses go to them. Certainly `button` can, but the OP said specifically `input`, so... I was basically generalizing.

Comment: Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/39yUG/4/ . It only works if I remove that your line.

Comment: @TonyFire: I don't see an `input` elements in that fiddle. But my answer had a typo (extra `);` after the closing `}` of the `if`), which I've fixed.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought putting input there would select all kind of input forms

Comment: @TonyFire: That fiddle doesn't have any kind of form field at all. No `input`, no `select`, no `button`...

Comment: I thought it was strange that the script did not work because it was supposed to work as long as you weren't typing. Which you couldn't because there were no form fields. But your solution worked, just my ignorance that kept it from working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The event already contains the target object, so we can check it like this:

```
if($(event.target).is('input,select,button')) return;
```

We put the object event.target in `$()` to refere the DOM element. We can check the element's type or whatever we need (`.hasClass()` for example)

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: don't forget textarea!